# Download curl source for building

Tags: curl, libcurl, tortoisegit

Running windows XP 32bit OS.

I need to download curl (libcurl?) in order to build the latest curllib.dll and  libcurl_imp.lib code on Windows.

I have installed tortoisegit...but now what?

Curl specifies that I run the below command -

> git close git://github.com/badger/curl.git

but there is no git.exe in the tortoisegit download?

Could someone please point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

Download the source from the webpresence. Open the project file lib/*.dsw in Visual Studio (i used 2010) compile and it works. That worked for me pretty well as long as i tried to include ssl. After 10 hours of hopeless tries to compile openSSL i switched to linux and downloaded the binaries from the repository. Worked instant like a charm.

Greets

Answer (score 0):

That gives you the full source code. Then you need to build that into a lib, possibly using the instructions in the [docs/INSTALL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) file.